# Change route/folder precedence in IIS/ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis

If i have a folder named xxx and a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "TestRoute",
    "xxx/{action}",
    new { controller ="xxx", action="Index" }
);
```

By default, when i request /xxx, IIS will try to return a directory listing, but I want my route to have precedence over folders/files on requests.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a post that describes your issue and has a solution: http://forums.asp.net/t/1251156.aspx/1

Here's the meat of the answer on the link I provided:

By default, DirectoryListingModule take precedence over UrlMappingsModule. Fortunately, it is possible to change the order of UrlMappingsModule and DirectoryListingModule.

Goes to IIS7 Manager -> Modules, in the right pane, click View Ordered List, you can then use Move Down, Move Up to change the order of modules.

Comment: Is it possible to override this in web.config instead of in IIS itself?

Comment: @josh As long as modules are locked in your applicationHost.config file I don't think you can override this in web.config. This is something I've never tried before so I don't really know much more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered an inconsistent behavior (it tries to perform directory listing first on my dev machine with IIS 8, but works fine on IIS 10 on multiple Windows servers, in spite of IIS 10 instances having DirectoryListingModule before UrlMappingsModule).

`bbak` solution is the best, but if you want to avoid changing the configuration on multiple machines, the easiest way is to ensure that there is no name collision between solution first level folders and routes.